# Android Studio 3: useDeprecatedNdk no longer supported

Tags: android, android-ndk, pjsip, android-studio-3.0

I am developing an app using [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/). I have `.so` libraries (compiled using `ndk-r10e`) that they were working well before upgrade to Android Studio 3.0. This upgrade 
no longer supports `useDeprecatedNdk` and console says to follow this tutorial:
[Migrate from ndkCompile](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html?utm_source=android-studio#ndkCompile)

I made this tutorial done and build is OK but running an app returns error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':pjsua:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libpjsua2.so'
```

I have already tried `clean` and `Invalidate cache / restart`.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put this into gradle and it seems it's working now...

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libpjsua2.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi/libpjsua2.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libpjsua2.so'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the latest samples, they use wild cards to deal with all the duplicate `.so` files.

It is like:

```
pickFirst **
```

Like in [this link](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html).